# Статус код 405, при запросе с фронтенда выдает ошибку

Tags: javascript, json, spring-boot, клиент-сервер, xmlhttprequest

**Что делаю?**

Я отправляю запрос из браузера (js код) на backend (Spring Boot).
Отправляю POST-методом с телом запроса (body).

**Что получаю?**

Получаю ошибку HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed.

**Что пробовал?**

1. Пробовал отправлять запросы с фронта через fetch, $AJAX, XMLHttpRequest и axios (не работает).
2. Пробовал отправлять запросы через POSTMAN и CURL (работает).
3. Пробовал без body отправлять get запрос, всё работает, на фронт возвращается Excel-файл.
4. Пробовал добавлять CORS, NO-CORS (с этим тоже были проблемы) в запросе на фронте.
5. Пробовал добавлять @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://127.0.0.1") на бэкенде.
6. Пробовал отправлять запрос с включенным локальным сервером VS Code (localhost) и, открывая HTML страницу из папки (по абсолютному пути).
7. Пробовал добавлять produces, consumes в PostMapping на бэке.
8. Пробовал добавлять заголовки в запрос (например, "Content-Type: application/json")

**Что нужно получать, в чем проблема?**

Нужно получать excel файл сгенерированный на backend'е, вставив в него данные из объекта, переданного в body POST-запроса.
Проблема в том, что я не могу отправить JSON На бэкенд, С обработкой и возвратом проблем вроде нет, все получилось (когда пробовал через GET без body). Почему-то падает POST запрос.

**Код метода отправляющего запрос с фронта:**

```js
   
    function initExport(form) {
        exportBtn.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {requestServer(e, form)}, false);
        // exportBtn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {requestServer(e, form)}, false);
    }

    

    export function requestServer(e, formData) {
        e.preventDefault()
        e.stopPropagation()
        const url = `${backendUrl}:${backendPort}/${exportRequestMapping}`;

        axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: url,
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            data: JSON.stringify({"a": 123, "b": 234})
        })
    }
```

**Код кнопки отправления запроса (пробовал 2-мя способами):**

```html
     <form method="get" action="http://localhost:8099/gen-excel" >
         <input type="submit" value="Экспортировать" class="btn btn-primary mt-15 ml-15" id="exportBtn">
     </form>
     <!-- <input type="click" value="Экспортировать" class="btn btn-primary mt-15 ml-15" id="exportBtn"> -->
```

**Код контроллера на бэке:**

```java
    @RestController
    public class FormController {
        private final ExcelUtil excelUtil;
        @Autowired
        public FormController(ExcelUtil excelUtil) {
            this.excelUtil = excelUtil;
        }
        @PostMapping(path = "/gen-excel",
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE,
            consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        public ResponseEntity<Resource> getExcel(@RequestBody HashMap<String, String> map) throws IOException {

             excelUtil.createExcelFile("form.xls");
             Resource resource = excelUtil.getExcelFile("form.xls");
             return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .header("Content-Disposition",
                        "file; filename=" +
                                "filename.xls")
                .body(resource);

        }
    }
```

**Заголовки:**

[image: заголовки ответов и запросов]

Answer (score 0):

Сделал пока так, работает. Файл планирую получать другим запросом (GET). Который уже протестировал.

```js
export function requestServer(e, formData) {

    e.preventDefault()
    e.stopPropagation()
    const url = `${backendUrl}:${backendPort}/${exportRequestMapping}`;

    console.log(JSON.stringify(formToDtoObject(formData)))


    fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(formToDtoObject(formData))
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => console.log(JSON.stringify(response)))

}
```

```java
    @PostMapping(path = "/gen-excel", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public String genExcel(@RequestBody Form form) throws IOException {
        return "TEST TEXT";
    }
```